# How to check if field is valid with validator #1 OR validator #2 in YUP

Tags: yup

I need to check if field contains phone number OR email.

Something like this:

```
const phoneOrEmailValidationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  phoneOrEmail: Yup.string()
    .oneOfValidators(
      [Yup.string().email(), Yup.string().min(5)],
      "must be phone or email"
    )
    .required("Required phoneOrEmail"),
});
```

Is it possible to do it with YUP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const phoneOrEmailValidationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  phoneOrEmail: Yup.lazy((value) => {
    if (value.indexOf("@") === -1) {
      return Yup.string().min(5);
    }
    return Yup.string().email();
  }),
});
```

If you can determine at runtime which validation to run, you can use this method. Not sure how you would do this if you couldn't determine which validation to run.